# Email Preview not working in Ruby on Rails ActionMailer API-Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

ActionMailer works just fine in my RoR App in API-Only-Mode. BUT the preview is not working. When I open my local path
http://localhost:3001/rails/mailers/

I get an empty page. See console log below.

What can I do to make the preview work? Maybe there is some module missing in the API-Mode?

Rails 5.2.3, Ruby 2.6.0, Puma.

```
Started GET "/rails/mailers/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-05-14 17:38:35 +0200
Processing by Rails::MailersController#index as HTML
  Rendering /Users/fcandi/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/templates/rails/mailers/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered /Users/fcandi/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/templates/rails/mailers/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: It looks like it might be rendering an empty default layout. Did you set a `config.action_mailer.preview_path` in your `application.rb` (or find the default value) and create a `foo_mailer_preview.rb` file (named after whatever your mailer is named?

Comment: Thanks, @JayDorsey now it is working :D